# Process form values via loop

Tags: php

I have a form that has fields with the following name

```
<input type="text" name="value[]">
<input type="text" name="value[]">
<input type="text" name="value[]">
```

On form submit I need to run a query and store each submitted non-empty values into my db. How do I do that? I suppose I need to run loop but not sure how and especially to avoid blank field submissions.

Comment: i would first suggest do a `print_r($_GET['value'])` for get or `print_r($_POST['value'])` for post and see what prints out.

Comment: Oh, it submits fine, I can see all fields submitted and which ones have values or not. How do I integrate this in my code though?

Comment: well, what is your code?

Comment: I don't have any yet. I was thinking something along the lines: for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($value); ++$i)
{
    //db query
} but this does not weed out blank submissions. Do I just run a loop and validate before db query is run?

Comment: why not to add some condition inside of the loop? and make db query conditional (note that you don't have $value but $_POST['value'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['value'] as $val)
{
   if($val != "")
   {
       //process query, $val will have the tag's value
   }
}
```

Comment: checking for isset after assigning a variable makes no sense.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Edited to restrict empty values.

Comment: Can't I add TRIM and then check if ($val != '') or (!empty($val) ?

Comment: You're @santa. you can do anything at your wish, don't you? sure you can add trim, nobody forbids you that. empty() is redundant too.

Comment: @santa I edited, it just checks for empty strings like you said. Sure you can add a trim() to it for extra security.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think trim() will help with security but it'll clean input a bit. For security I usually run all input through a class that takes care of sanitation.

Comment: @santa such classes often only spoil your data but give no real security

Comment: @santa that's what i meant lol. 'secure' the loop from whitespace input xD

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel actually the one I use mainly looks for script inserts. Fairly benign and quite fast. I'd rather strip someone's HTML rather than run a risk of having someone's code stored in my db. But this is a subject for a whole different discussion.